# Mensaje de error al no encontrar registro en la base de datos

Tags: asp.net, webservice, aplicación-web

Tengo una web hecha en ASP.NET con un web service, el cliente hace una consulta y este debe devolver un precio.

La página funciona bien excepto cuando se busca algún registro que no existe; necesito que cuando la consulta no encuentre el registro en la base de datos muestre un mensaje de error o lo lleve a otra página.

Este es el **código** que tengo:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     String codigo = Request.QueryString["codigo"];
     Referencia.WebServiceSoapClient WS = new Referencia.WebServiceSoapClient();
     DataSet ds = WS.WSBuscar(codigo);
     Label2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
     Label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Usa:

```
try
{
    "Acá va el código que intentará ejecutar"
}
catch
{
    "Acá va la alerta de error que desees mostrar"
}
```

Cabe aclarar que la alerta la debes configurar ya sea con un label o un script con `Response.Write()`